# Libgdx stuck generating an app

Tags: java, android, libgdx

When I click on the downloaded libgdx file I select run with Java then the libgdx window pops up I check android (and tried to check desktop too) and leave the names default and some times I tried to change them and for extensions I leave it as default the only one checked is box 2D.

Its says in the little console below that it's generating an app in my desired path then its just stuck there for hours.

(I checked task manager and its not using almost any resources other than 60 mbs of ram)

Comment: Please be clearer about what you are trying to achieve, what the issue is and what you've tried so far to resolve the issue. Also, consider posting relevant code snippets and have a look at [this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem could possibly happen if the application cannot write into the destination folder you choose. So avoid making the destination folder inside the system32 folder or such.

Answer (score 0):

Run the jar file from the command prompt to see the exception it generates which should explain the problem:

- Hold down the Windows button and tap the 'r' key.
- In the dialog type 'cmd' then enter.
- Copy this text using ctrl-c, include all quotes. Adjust the file names to point to your Java VM runtime and your downloaded
  gdx-setup.jar file:  "C:\Program
  Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.222.10-hotspot\bin\java.exe" -jar "C:\Users\keith\Downloads\gdx-setup.jar"
- Paste the text into the command prompt by pressing ctrl-insert (the zero key on the numpad). Alternatively, tap the top left icon,
  then edit, then paste.
- See what the specific exception is in the cmd console when the gdx setup program runs.